# linux network monitoring, average MBps each 1hr

Tags: networking, debian, monitoring

I want to monitor the average network usage for my Debian server.

Ive tried to mess with `dstat`, `ntop` and couple other programs but nothing seems to work like I want to.

Basically I want a program/script that outputs an average network stats each X time.
Whats the best way to do what I need ?

Greetings,

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at `netstat` command. Its a simple way to get network status and statistics. A guide on how to use it: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-iface.netstat.html

You're probably looking for `netstat -i`, which will output long-term average networking statistics for all configured interfaces, plus error counters and other useful things.

Alternatively (and a bit less simply), Sar can output a huge range of data and is great for a local measure of "What is happening to X for duration Y".

This is a fair guide on how to use it: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples

You're looking for section (9) which reads:

9. Report network statistics (sar -n)

This reports various network statistics. For example: number of packets received (transmitted) through the network card, statistics of packet failure etc.,. “1 3” reports for every 1 seconds a total of 3 times.

```
sar -n KEYWORD
KEYWORD can be one of the following:

DEV – Displays network devices vital statistics for eth0, eth1, etc.,
EDEV – Display network device failure statistics
NFS – Displays NFS client activities
NFSD – Displays NFS server activities
SOCK – Displays sockets in use for IPv4
IP – Displays IPv4 network traffic
EIP – Displays IPv4 network errors
ICMP – Displays ICMPv4 network traffic
EICMP – Displays ICMPv4 network errors
TCP – Displays TCPv4 network traffic
ETCP – Displays TCPv4 network errors
UDP – Displays UDPv4 network traffic
SOCK6, IP6, EIP6, ICMP6, UDP6 are for IPv6
ALL – This displays all of the above information. The output will be very long.
```

Thus, `# sar -n DEV 1 2` will report on network devices one every second two times. If you wanted a fair average in a given time frame, you could specify a large "duration" value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
For some reason sar network monitor is not working for me. Ive fixed couple issues but it still not work.
Ive managed to run "dstat -n --bits 600 >> /log/network" and its exactly what I needed, outputs average network load every 10 minutes. But now I have next issue, I dont know how to assign proper date to every line.

Comment: okay Ive done it.

dstat -tn 600 > /root/dstat &